# Send PHP Link data from ajax call to different page onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im busy learning ajax. I have a reservation page and a checkout page.

**What I want to do**

User types the renter name into a search box, matching names gets fetched from db and displayed dynamically.

Like so:

*reservations.php*

[image]

When user clicks the highlighted link, I would like the reservation Id to get passed to the checkout page. THUS, ***Im looking for a way to pass the reservation ID to another/different page, which I can use for data processing on the checkout page.***

*checkout.php*

[image]

**CODE**

*SEARCH / JQUERY*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchbox").on('keyup',function () {
            var key = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url:'fetch.php',
                type:'GET',
                data:'keyword='+key,
                beforeSend:function () {
                    $("#results").slideUp('fast');
                },
                success:function (data) {
                    $("#results").html(data);
                    $("#results").slideDown('fast');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="main">
    <div id="header"><h1>Find Names</h1></div>
    <div id="content">
        <input type="search" name="keyword" placeholder="Search Names" id="searchbox">
        <div id="results"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*FETCH.PHP*

```
  if($_GET['keyword'] && !empty($_GET['keyword']))
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','*****'); //Connection to my database
        $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
        $keyword="%$keyword%";
        $query = "select renter_name from reservations where renter_name like ?";
        $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('s',$keyword);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->store_result();
        if($statement->num_rows() == 0) // so if we have 0 records acc. to keyword display no records found
        {
            echo '<div id="item">Ah snap...! No results found :/</div>';
            $statement->close();
            $conn->close();

        }
        else {
            $statement->bind_result($name);
            while ($statement->fetch()) //outputs the records
            {
                echo "<div id='item'>$name</div>";
            };
            $statement->close();
            $conn->close();
        };
    };
```

*DB*

[image]

Any help or advice in terms of implementation greatly appreciated!

Comment: That would be very similar to what you already have with the difference that you need to catch the `click` event where you are now already catching the `keyUp` event. What is the exact problem?

Comment: @jeroen I need to 1)Get the res_id from name match in the searchbox, based on name user clicked 2) pass & populate it to the checkout screen form field...hope that makes sence

Comment: Why do I have a close vote on this question, I did put a lot of effort into the question trying to provide as much details as possible while conforming to guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use links and queries.
At first echo a link instead of a div:

```
echo "<a href='yourpage.php?id=$name'>$name</a>";
```

And on your page simply do:

```
<?php
echo $_GET[" id"];
?>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much!! one last question if you don't mind....I need not get the `res_id` associated with the name..thus, I would need to change my sql query `$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
        $keyword="%$keyword%";
        $query = "select renter_name, from reservations where renter_name like ?"` When I add `query = "select res_id, renter_name, from reservations where renter_name like ?";` I get the error `Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement` Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: @Marilee: you didnt mistype $query (you wrote query= in your comment)?

Comment: Sorry It should have read, '$query`, working on it now, think I am on the correct path fingers crossed